# Chrome icon randomly changing to something else

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dock

Since about 2 weeks my chrome icon randomly changes to the one pictured. Turning off chrome fixes it, but soon after restart the weird icon comes back. What is it, how do I fix this?

[image: weird icon]

Comment: I've seen this issue on a friend's computer across multiple apps, so far no fix. It's possible it's specific to Chrome, but I'd be willing to bet it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how I fixed it on my machine (it was affecting a different app though):

Boot your Mac in Safe Mode by holding the shift key after hearing the startup chime. Sign in and open Chrome. Then restart normally. This should fix the problem.

If that doesn’t work, I’d suggest trying a Chrome reinstall.

If a Chrome reinstall doesn’t do it, I’d try reinstalling macOS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to fix it:

- Open Finder, go to Applications, locate Google Chrome, then right click and choose Get Info.
  [image]
- Click on the icon at the top left
  [image]
- Press Cmd+C and then Cmd+V (Copy then Paste), it may ask your pw to make changes.
- Exit get info window, and restart google chrome. It should be back to normal.